# Apostrophe is showing up as â€™ in windows, chrome browser

Tags: html, utf-8, jsx

I have a static app that uses react & html5.  I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head of my `index.html` file.  BUT for some reason, apostrophe's are being rendered as `â€™`.  This does not happen locally.  It only happens on a windows computer.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your web server is serving the file with the wrong `Content-Type` HTTP headers…

Comment: No, I think it's a windows issue.  I don't see this happening on any macs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the character encoding for a webpage in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/a/1160292/376602)